# Reference variable in alias

Tags: linux, bash, shell, alias

I want to define an alias which references an environment variable in real time. For example, how can I make an alias to echo the value of `N`?

```
$ N=4
$ alias sayn="echo $N"
$ N=2
$ sayn
4
```

Comment: You would be better off with a function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you define your alias using double quotes, the `$N` is expanded before definition and your alias actually is `echo 4`.

Try this :

```
$N=4
$alias sayn='echo $N'
$N=2
$sayn
2
```